# Header is being shifted when page is resized

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, text-align

I am making a website with a responsive design so that it still looks good and resizes well on different devices.

It all works well, apart from the h1 text. I have a container of fixed width 800px, that changes to a width of 100% at the appropriate screen size. The header text is centered, however, when the screen size changes and the container becomes 100% width, the header is now off-center, slightly shifted to the right.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>My Website!</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
* {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}

body {
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#container {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: white;
}

/* Resizability (Responsive Web Design) */

@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {

    #container {
        width: 100%;
    }

}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwswxqza/).

Add `max-width: 100%` and `width: auto` property like:

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {

    #container {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
        border: 1px solid red; /*only for demonstration */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's happening because of the `20px` padding which you're applying to your `container` on the left and right. Please try this CSS for the responsive part:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 840px) {

    #container {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 20px 0px;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/6d8296ag/2/

the issue was because of the `padding` the `width` was `100%` and also padding was added so the total `width` increased to 100% + `padding` using `box-sizing:border-box` which gives `padding/border` from inside

in you fiddle there was horizontal scroller by which was because of the `padding` and `width`

for responsive design using `box-sizing:border-box` is important

```
* {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```